# ImageKit in Django

Tags: python, django, imagekit, django-imagekit

I am implementing ImageKit in a Django app and I have everything set up properly to my knowledge. When I run the command

```
$python manage.py ikflush main
```

the command seems to run fine but nothing appears to happen. None of the images get resized or stored and cannot be accessed.

***main.models.py:***

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    original = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/product-images/zoom/')

    class IKOptions:
        spec_module = 'main.specs'
        cache_dir = 'uploads/cache'
        image_field = 'original'
```

***main.specs.py:***

```
from imagekit.specs import ImageSpec 
from imagekit import processors 

class ResizeSmall(processors.Resize): 
    width = 230 
    height = 289 
    crop = False

class SmallImage(ImageSpec): 
    access_as = 'small_image' 
    pre_cache = True 
    processors = [ResizeSmall]
```

***in template: (prints nothing)***

```
{% for image in images %}
    {{ image.small_image }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to debug this? I really want to use ImageKit for this but I have never implemented it before. **Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ProductImage model needs to inherit from imagekit.models.ImageModel in instead of models.Model.

Comment: That was it! You are the man! Now if I can just get Jpeg support working in PIL... haha.

Answer (score 1):

This may just be a formatting mistake in the question and not in your code.  But `IKOptions` should be nested in your model class:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    # fields, etc...
    class IKOptions:
        # ...
```

Also, before you run ikflush, did you add ImageKit to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings file?

Comment: Yeah that is just an error from how stackoverflow rendered it. I have fixed it now so it should reflect that it is nested inside the model now.

Also I do have 'imagekit' added to INSTALLED_APPS